# Returning 1 or 0 in specific SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have three columns in the table MYTABLE (ID, NUM, NAMES). There is a column NAMES. I need to check on NAMES column to see if the first name is JACK or BRUCE and the corresponding NUM column = 0. If the match is found, return 1 else 0.

```
ID NUM NAMES    
1  1   'TOM'
2  1   'MIKE'
3  0   'JACK'
4  1   'MICKY'
5  0   'BRUCE'
```

I've came up with the following query:

```
select *
  case NAMES in ('JACK', 'BRUCE') and NUM=0 then 1 else 0 end as MYNAMES
from MYTABLE;
```

That does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works ([SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69ea0/1)):

```
SELECT id, num,
    CASE WHEN names IN ('JACK', 'BRUCE') AND num=0
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS mynames
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select  case
        when exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable
        where   name in ('JACK', 'BRUCE')
                and NUM = 0
        )
        then 1
        else 0
        end
from    dual
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc6d2/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when NAMES in ('JACK','BRUCE') AND NUM = 0
            then 1
            else 0
       end
from your_table
```